# Deploying AWS Lambda Python With Bitbucket Pipeline and Serverless Framework

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bitbucket, pipeline

I'm using serverless framework to deploy a Lambda in AWS.
Lambda runtime is: python3.9; Lambda use python libraries like: pandas, awswrangler, click

I deploy the lambda in 2 ways:

- - Bitbucket pipeline
- - *serverless deploy* command

In both ways I get error: `Resource handler returned message: "Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes`

So I tried with:

```
package:
  patterns:
    - '!.tox/**'
    - '!events/**'
    - '!git-hook/**'
    - '!test/**'
    - '!venv3/**'
    - '!.coverage'
    - '!.coveragerc'
    - '!.flake8'
    - '!logs.txt'
    - '!setup.py'
    - '!tox.ini'

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-existing-s3
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-step-functions
  - serverless-deployment-bucket
custom:
  defaultRegion: "eu-central-1"
  pythonRequirements:
    zip: true
```

And deploy by command line.
In this case, when I run the Lambda on AWS, I get error message: `Unable to import module 'serverless_myproject.lambda_handler': Unable to import required dependencies: click|wrangler:`

Any suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: Are you using Lambda layers for the non-standard libs?

Comment: As the error tells you, you've hit the limit for your AWS Lambda function code size. If you need more than 250MB, you can use Lambda with Docker Image (10GB limit): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html

Comment: @CaptainCaveman Hi, I use just these libs: boto3==1.26.5
click==8.0.4
awswrangler==2.17.0
pytz==2022.4
pyathena==2.14.0

Comment: The 'Unable to import required dependencies' is thrown when you are using non-standard python libs and haven't added a Lambda Layer to your Lambda function containing the library.